# Explicit form for the total variation measure of a symmetric matrix-valued measure

Tags: measure-theory, symmetric-matrices, trace, total-variation, vector-measure

Let $X$ be a [locally compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space).
Consider the set $M(X; S^d)$ of real symmetric matrix-valued measures on $X$, that is, the set of countably (with respect to the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) $\| \cdot \|_F$) additive functions $u \colon B(X) \to S^d$ with $u(\emptyset) = 0$ (and [tr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra))$(u(X)) < \infty$), where $B(X)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $X$.
The [total variation measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_norm_of_vector-valued_measures) $| u |$ associated to $u \in M(X; S^d)$ is defined by
$$
| u |(E)
= \sup\left\{  \sum_{k \in \mathbb N} \| u(A_k) \|_{F}: (A_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \subset B(X) \text{ is a pairwise disjoint partition of } E \right\}
$$
for $E \in B(X)$.
For a spike train, a linear combination of [Dirac measures](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dirac+measure),
$$
u = \sum_{k = 1}^{N} P_k \delta_{\{ x_k \}},
$$
where $(P_k)_{k = 1}^{N} \subset S^d$ and $(x_k)_{k = 1}^{N} \subset X$, we have
$$
| u | = \sum_{k = 1}^{N} \| P_k \|_F \delta_{x_k}.
$$

### My question

I am wondering if there is an explicit form for $\| u \|$ for non-discrete measures (perhaps we need to choose another norm than $\| \cdot \|_F$, e.g. the [nuclear norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms) $\text{tr}(| \cdot |)$ or the [spectral norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_p-norms) $\| \cdot \|_2$?). It would be great if we can somehow relate $| u |$ to the associated trace measure $\text{tr}(u)$.

**Thoughts.**
Since the trace norm $A \mapsto \text{tr}(| A |)$ reduces to the trace $A \mapsto \text{tr}(A)$ for $A \in S_+^d$, is the trace measure just the total variation measure if the norm is the trace norm instead of the Frobenius norm?

I was thinking that we can decompose a symmetric matrix $P$ into the the difference of two positive (semi)definite matrices $P_1 - P_2$, so maybe $\| P \| = \| P_1 \| + \| P_2 \|$ for such a decomposition?

Another thought is that the entries $u_{i, j}$ of a real symmetric matrix-valued measure are real-valued measures in their one right, with total variation measure $| u_{i, j} | = u_{i, j}^+ + u_{i, j}^-$ ([Hahn-Jordan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem#Jordan_measure_decomposition)).
Is there any relationship between the $| u_{i, j} |$ and $\| u \|$?

---

The motivation for this is that integrals of functions with respect to $\text{tr}(u)$ are much easier to handle that with respect to the abstract non-closed form $\| u \|$.
For measures $u$ valued only in the positive semidefinite matrices $S_+^d$, we have that they are absolutely continuous with respect to $\text{tr}(u)$, but this is not the case for symmetric-valued matrix measures.
For $P \in S^d$ we have the inequality $\| P \|_2 \le \| P \|_F \le \text{tr}(P)$.

---

We also have the following relationship between the trace measure and the total variation measure: the pre-dual of $M(X; S^d)$ are the continuous functions on $X$ with values in $S^d$ that vanish at infinity, $C_0(X; S^d)$ via the duality pairing (see Singer's theorem)
$$
\langle u, f \rangle_{M(X; S^d) \times C_0(X; S^d)}
:= \int_{X} \langle f(x), u'(x) \rangle_{F} \, \text{d}| u |(x)
$$
where $u \in M(X; S^d)$, $f \in C_0(X; S^d)$ and $u'$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $u$ with respect to $| u |$.
On the other hand, we have, due to the linearity of the integral,
$$
\langle u, f \rangle_{M(X; S^d) \times C_0(X; S^d)}
= \text{tr}\left( \int_{X} f(x) \, \text{d}u(x) \right)
= \int_{X} \langle f(x), u_{\text{tr}}'(x) \rangle \, \text{d}[\text{tr}(u)](x),
$$
where $u_{\text{tr}}'$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $u$ with respect to $\text{tr}(u)$.

---

### Update

Thanks so @Adam's comment, we must only consider *positive* matrix measures $u \in M(X; S_+^d)$, because any $u \in M(X, S^d)$ can be pointwise decomposed as $u = O \otimes P$, where $O$ is orthogonal-matrix valued and $P \in M(X; S_+^d)$. Since the three matrix norms proposed above are al unitarily invariant, we have $| u | = | P |$.

Comment: Possibly you can find a [polar decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure#Variation_of_a_complex_measure_and_polar_decomposition), similarly to a complex measure?

Comment: @Adam Thank you for your reply, this is an interesting idea. By the polar decomposition for matrices, I can write $u = U \otimes P$, where $U$ is a orthogonal matrix-valued measure and $P$ is a $S_+^d$-valued measure. Since the Frobenius, spectral and trace norm are each unitarily invariant, no matter which of these norms I choose to define the total variation measure, I have $| u | = | P |$.

Comment: This would mean that this question reduces to $S_+^d$-valued measures.